# Store integers (32 bit) in array (which type? ) C programming

Tags: c, arrays, types, integer

I got 32 bit integers that i want to store them ***in a dynamically allocated array*** and then send this array to others processes (in MPI )

```
   int32_t data;
```

I am confused ,which type of data should i use so that i can have an array of size lets say , ***N*** with 32 bit integers?
How can this be implemented?

Comment: I think you may want to learn about malloc/realloc/free.

Comment: How about `int32_t* array = malloc(sizeof(int32_t)*N);`?

Comment: I believe `int32_t* array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * N);` is better.

Comment: @Shiva a very interesting way to encourage type safety, I have not seen that before

Comment: Actually you should use [`calloc`](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20060330071917) instead of multiplying.

Comment: @Zulan: It depends on the application imo. With `calloc`, you have the extra overhead of setting each element to its default value. `malloc` is faster and preferable if you don't need that initialisation.

Comment: @Shiva It's about the overflow, not the zero initialization. Also the zero initialization can and is optimized away by common implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... which type of data should i use so that i can have an array of size lets say , `N` with 32 bit integers?

```
// The type of `p` is a pointer to a 32-bit signed integer.
int32 *p;
```

> How can this be implemented?

```
// No need to use `int32_t` in the next line of code
//              size of 1 element ---v-------v * v--- element count
p = /* no cast needed here */ malloc(sizeof *p * N);
if (p == NULL) return Handle_Failure();

for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
  // do something with p[i]
  p[i] = 42;
}

// free when done
free(p);
```